# Remove the gap between the image and the Container

Tags: html, css

[image]

You can the image, and this the demo http://jsfiddle.net/yJUH4/8/

As you can see in the picture a small gap is coming between image and the Container. Image is already give css `vertical-align:middle`. When i increase the height of the container it works perfectly. Waiting for a good answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `vertical-align:top` on the `img`

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/56JNq/)

By default, the `vertical-align` property isn't top, but rather `baseline`. By simply setting it to top, you can achieve the desired result.

Comment: Or 'bottom'. The key is to set it to something other than 'baseline', which allows for character descenders and is dependent on line-height.

Comment: @isherwood Exactly. `middle`, `top`, and `bottom` all work.

Answer (score 1):

One other option...

```
td {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yJUH4/11/

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

should fix it.